# How to SELECT query including a junction table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have three tables:

**students**

```
student_ID
Firstname
Lastname
```

**course**

```
course_ID
course_Name
semester
```

**enroll**

```
student_ID
course_ID
```

> enroll is the junction table instead of having the many to many relationships.

I need to create a SELECT statement that will return four columns: `student_ID` `Firstname` `course_ID` `course_Name` from two tables after enrollment. Here in the enroll table, I can only see the which student_ID is enrolled in which course_ID by there primary key. But if I want to see what is the course name reference with specific course_ID enrolled by the specific student_ID, how should I write the query.

Actually I want to fetch the `student_ID`, `Firstname`, `course_ID`, `course_name` in a website to see which is students are enrolled in which `course_name` not only the `course_name`. That is why I think I will need to write a select query.

It will be helpful if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: `mysql <> sql-server`... pick one!

Comment: Once you get clear on what RDBMS you are using I suggest doing some research on joins.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for mysql or sql server, you didn't say which you were using. You might want to limit it or use a where clause if you have a lot or rows.

```
SELECT students.studen_ID, students.Firstname, course.course_ID, course.course_Name
FROM students
JOIN enroll ON (enroll.student_ID = students.student_ID)
JOIN course ON (course.course_ID = enroll.coruse_ID)
```